# How to write reusable code in node.js

Tags: design, node.js

I am trying to understand how to design node.js applications, but it seems there is something I can't grasp about asynchronous programming.

Let's say my application needs to access a database. In a synchronous environment I would implement a data access class with a read() method, returning an associative array.

In node.js, because code is executed asynchronously, this method can't return a value, so, after execution, it will have to "do" something as a side effect. It will then contain some code which does something else than just reading data.

Let's suppose I want to call this method multiple times, each time with a different success callback. Since the callback is included in the method itself, I can't find a clean way to do this without either duplicating the method or specifying all possible callbacks in a long switch statement.

What is the proper way to handle this problem? Am I approaching it the wrong way?

Comment: It is not very clear what is your problem, maybe rephrase it. I'd have two comments: 1. Maybe you just need to get used to async/callback way of doing things, I do not see anything like "unmanageable code soup" there. 2. Ad "loosely coupled classes": do you really need "classes" there? Classes are not needed to do OO neither to do good design. Maybe change the title.

Comment: I'm not certain what this code soup is either?

Comment: I changed the title and rephrased the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you can pass functions as parameters, it is common to pass a "callback" function to these sorts of functions.  So, for example, you may have a "read" function that looks like this:

```
function getUser(userId, callback) {
  var mydbAPI = something;
  var myQuery = somethingElse;

  mydbAPI.getUser(myQuery, function(data) {
    //parse data a little here:
    myParsedData = ...;

    callback(myParsedData);
  });
}
```

You can then call the read method like this:

```
getUser(userId, function(parsedData) {
  //...do something with parsedData
});
```